Ardupilot ROS 2 with SITL is not working. DDS no ping response exiting. Link 1 down in sitl
Thanks already if you can help me with this stubborn issue. I am trying to setup Ardupilot with ROS2, right now i am just working on simulation on example copters.
With this command: sim_vehicle.py -v copter --console --map -w
I am getting the expected results.
sim_vehicle.py -v copter --console --map -w
When i try to use this command: ros2 launch ardupilot_sitl sitl_dds_udp.launch.py transport:=udp4 synthetic_clock:=True wipe:=False model:=quad speedup:=1 slave:=0 instance:=0 defaults:=$(ros2 pkg prefix ardupilot_sitl)/share/ardupilot_sitl/config/default_params/copter.parm,$(ros2 pkg prefix ardupilot_sitl)/share/ardupilot_sitl/config/default_params/dds_udp.parm sim_address:=127.0.0.1 master:=tcp:127.0.0.1:5760 sitl:=127.0.0.1:5501
I get this:
enter image description here
Morever, the command doesnt launch any mavproxy so i am using mavproxy.py --master=tcp:127.0.0.1:5760 --console --map for launching it in seperate terminal but its console says link 1 down.
Also, because of this no ros2 nodes are visible. especially ros2 node info /ardupilot_dds.
I am Using Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS2 Humble.
I have tried to install all the dependencies but its still not working, also i am not sure how to check ardupilots version. I am just expecting to make the sitl launch properly and show standard ros2 nodes and topics.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
